# Tensorflow - High CPU usage while using GPU

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, cpu

We aim to reduce CPU usage during inference by moving to GPU. However, when we run on GPU, the CPU usage is still high. Using the timeline output from RunMetadata and RunOptions class, we get the following profiling:
[CPU and GPU Activity during inference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SkUb.png)
The 6th row is the CPU usage, 8th is GPU. The block with op "Unknown" have the same name as the GPU block. It is not a back-and-forth copy between host and device problem, as we can see by the first 4 rows. 
What we see is that CPU does something while the GPU work. I'd like to understand why this happens. Does anyone has a clue?

We are using Tensorflow-GPU 1.14 (C++ interface) on a Jetson TX2, jetpack 4.2.3, CUDA 10.2, capabilities 6.2.

Regards